# PHP $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] vs realpath(dirname(_FILE_))

Tags: php

I was wondering if one method was better than the other. I have been using the `$_SERVER` method to point to the current directory but is this method better than the `realpath(dirname(_FILE_))` method or is there any difference?

Comment: Using `_FILE_` would produce an error, possibly you mean `__FILE__`

Comment: `__DIR__` === `realpath(dirname(__FILE__))` PS: they are incomparable. You cannot prefer one over another just because they do different jobs.

Comment: `__DIR__ === dirname(__FILE__)` according to the PHP doc (http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) there's no mention of `realpath`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`$_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ]`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable returns a server setting. Specifically it returns:

> The document root directory under which the current script is executing, **as defined in the server's configuration file.**

The [`realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) )`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) function will return the path of the folder that the current script is actually residing.

One is returning the value of a server setting and the other evaluates to a file's path. In some cases, the values will be the same but you should be aware of the difference between the two.